# Why we need to set binding path and source xReference for Command and not just the property/command name?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

ListView --> ItemSource = { Binding Items } **//Works**

MenuItem -->  Command={ Binding MarkAsCompleted } **// is not wokring**

This **works only when I add path and Source**

Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.MarkAsCompletedCommand, Source={x:Reference TodoViewPage}}"

Why is this happening?!?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ViewCell>
    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
     <MenuItem Text="Complete" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.MarkAsCompletedCommand, Source={x:Reference TodoViewPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <StackLayout>
     <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
   </ViewCell>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Does your ViewModel for each Item in Items have the method `MarkAsCompleted`? Or where is the `MarkAsCompletedCommand` located?

Comment: MarkasCompleted is in the viewmodel class, I've a seperate todoItem class which is sending a list of todoitem objects to the viewmodel. Not each ToDoItem has this function. (I mean the markas completed function  not inside the ToDoItem Class it is a common funtion present in the viewmodel class).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MyCommand` is in `MyViewModel` in namespace `MyViewModels`, use `Source` `RelativeSource` with [`AncestorType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings#bind-to-an-ancestor) and `x:Type`.

Below the `Command` and `CommandParameter` `Bindings` refers to `MyViewModel` and the item in `ListView.ItemsSource`, respectively:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyViewModels"
...
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
         ...
           Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MyViewModel}}, 
                             Path=MyCommand}"
           CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
```